# How to Make 2 checkboxes to act as radio buttons in a group of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkboxlist, radio-group

I want to make two checkboxes to act as radio buttons in a group of checkboxes
As it is done here when we slect Front or Pocket it only checks one from them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'allPrintLocations',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {

      $('.printLocation_name label').click(function(event) {

        var checkNow = $(this).parent('.printLocation_name').find('input')
        if (checkNow.attr('checked')) {
          for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (checkNow.val() == response[i].id) {
              checkNow.removeAttr('checked', 'checked')
              document.getElementById("testview" + i).style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("numSelect" + i).style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        } else {
          for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
            document.getElementById("discribee" + i).name = response[i].name + "Suggestion";
            document.getElementById("Numbere" + i).name = response[i].name + "Colors";
            if (checkNow.val() == response[i].id) {
              checkNow.attr('checked', 'checked')
              document.getElementById("testview" + i).style.display = "block";

              document.getElementById("numSelect" + i).style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById("label" + i).innerHTML = 'Describe what you would like designed on the ' + response[i].name + ' of the shirt.';
            }
          }
        }

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Select_Boxes">
  <div class="all_print_location">
    <label class="main_labels">
                                    Select printed location
                                </label>
    <div class="allLocations">
      @foreach ($product[0]->print_locations as $PL)

      <div class="printLocation_name">
        <input name="printLocations[]" type="checkbox" id="front" value="{{$PL->id}}">

        <label for="front">{{$PL->name}}</label>
      </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="PageInfo">
  <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, recusandae.</em></p>
</div>
@for($i=0;$i
<count($printLocations);$i++) <div id="testview{{$i}}" class="DiscribePrint" style="display: none">
  <label id="label{{$i}}" for="discribe" class="main_labels">
                                What You want on your Front
                            </label>
  <div class="main__discribe">
    <textarea id="discribee{{$i}}" name="" cols="20" rows="5" class="form-control form_class" placeholder="1. Please add notes/changes you need a numbered list.&#10;2. Please try to keep your notes concise.&#10;3. Please make sure to write the exact text you want on the shirt (event     name, date, venue, letters, school, chapter, sponors,etc"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="numSelect{{$i}}" class="number_Colors" style="display: none">
    <label for="Numbers" class="main_labels">
                                No. of colors
                            </label>
    <select id="Numbere{{$i}}" name="SelectColors" class="form-control form_class">
      <option value=""> Select Colors</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  @endfor
```

https://greekhouse.org/wizard/design

Here's My HTML Code
And Here is My Controller Function

```
 public function designDetailScreen(Request $request)
    {
        $printLocations = PrintLocations::all();
        $designID = $request->cookie('designID');
        $design = Designs::where('id',$designID)->get();
        $productID = $request->cookie('productID');
        $product = Products::where('id',$productID)->get();
        // dd($product[0]->print_locations);
        $data = array(
            "design" =>$design,
            "product" =>$product,
            "printLocations" => $printLocations
        );
        return view('web.designDetailScreen')->with($data);
    }
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Can you replace the template HTML with RENDERED HTML in a [mcve]? Assuming the ajax works, replace it with an example of a returned object

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons?

Comment: Instead of making checkboxes behave as radio buttons, why not just use radio buttons? Your users are most likely use to radio buttons behaving a certain way and checkboxes to behave in a different way. Changing that will probably just result in bad UX.

Comment: @mplungjan ajax is working. 
but i want to add something more.. 
like from first two options i just want to select one .. not both of them

Comment: What I meant was, we do not need to see your AJAX if it is working. So replace the ajax with an example object. Also you should not add an event handler in a success that uses the object returned in the ajax

Comment: If the ajax is reading the print location on load, why not read it on the server and include it in the initial HTML?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson actually there are 4 checkboxes .. i just want 2 checkboxes to act a radio while others work as checkboxes 
Like Four Options 
Front Back Pocket Sleeve 
I want to select one from front and back and then other two options too 
Like i want answer either Front Pocket Sleeve or Back Pocket Sleeve
I dont want both Front and Back simultaneously

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton because i dont want all fields to work as radio.. only two options should work as radio

Comment: @FarhanAli Why not just make those 2 fields radio buttons? You can even make neither of them selected by default. We are trying to tell you that modifying the existing checkboxes to behave differently is bad UX. If you really want to do this, just attach and event for both checkboxes which unchecks the box for the one not clicked.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton options are loading dynamically .. how could i make two of them radio buttons .. 
while i've to send back the array of all checked checkboxes

Comment: @FarhanAli Changing the way those 2 checkboxes work is going to require them to be treated specially anyways, so it will need modification either way. I'm just saying you may as well modify it in a way that doesn't change users expectations :)

Answer (score 0):

Fast and easy example of what you want, using jQuery:

```js
// select all checkboxes with class whatever, so the rest of the check-boxes are not affected 
$('.checkbox1').change(function(){
    // on changed diselect all without this, so you can have more than 2 check-boxes
    $('.checkbox1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1"><label for="checkbox1"></label></span><br />
<span class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" name="options[]" value="2"><label for="checkbox2"></label></span><br />
<span class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="checkbox3" name="options[]" value="3"><label for="checkbox3"></label></span><br />
<span class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" id="checkbox4" name="options[]" value="4"><label for="checkbox4"></label></span><br />
```